# How to auto open downloaded file in new tab in IE 11 or edge like file download work in chrome

Tags: javascript, windows, angular, internet-explorer

I am using windows 10 . I am using msSaveOrOpenBlob of javascript to download the blob return by the Ajax call in IE11. There I don't need any prompt like open, save while downloaded. The PDF file should be opened in new tab exactly like it happen in chrome. But not happening.

Then I checked with  tag. Then also it is not able to open without any prompt on click.

My code is like below. 
click here to download

File download option is enable and there is no option for prompt. PFB the prompt I am getting.[image]

Answer (score 0):

How a browser handles a PDF file depends on a combination of things.

1.) HTTP Headers

If you want the file to be treated as a file, vs. a "page" to load in the browser ensure you set the `content-disposition` to `attachment` and provide a `filename` with an `extension` (***with no spaces*** Firefox gets hung up on this) [HTTP Content-Disposition Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition)
e.g.

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.pdf"
```

2.) New Tab/new window

If you want your content to be loaded in another tab/window, you'll want to set the `target` attribute of your form/link to `_blank`.

3.) Browser settings

If the browser has a plugin installed (e.g. Adobe Acrobat) to handle PDFs, there are configurations in Acrobat to determine if the app opens PDFs separately in the application... or "embedded" in the browser.  Note that modern browsers (Chrome/Firefox/etc.) also have their own built in PDF rendering without a need for a plugin.

Comment: I have a blob, where type is application/pdf.  I am downloading it using msSaveOrOpenBlob in angular4. How do I achieve the expected behaviour. I have adobe plugin installed. Where would I set target="_blank" ?

Comment: Wait, what do you call in other browsers?... the `msSaveOrOpenBlob()` method is *specifically* designed to open the related application. spec: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772332(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I am checking msSaveOrOpenBlob is null or not. if null then opening url in new tab url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob); window.open(url). for chrome window.open() is working fine but for IE it is throwing access denied exception.

Comment: `window.open(url, nameWithNoHyphensOrSpaces, featuresStr);` should work fine in IE as long as the window name doesn’t contain spaces or a hyphen... AND you are **not** trying to launch it from a modalDialogWindow... AND you are not in a hybrid app container.

Comment: not working. In IE it is showing access denied exception. I have a blob response object. I have to download that. So creating url like let url = URL.createobjecturl(blob); window.open(url); this is working fine in chrome. But in IE it is not working. So here I had to use msSaveOrOpenBlob. Here file is getting downloaded but it is not able to open automatically in new tab like chrome. So is there any way to achieve  it in IE

Comment: I’m not sure how you build your blob, but if you want the content to open in a new window/tab you need it to be in the form of a URL. Can you get your data into a base 64 encoded *data:* URL? If so you can use window.open but set the URL to your base 64 encoded string.